# I ran ubuntu in vmplayer on windows 7: Working in ubuntu and access the DVD freezes ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu-10.04, vmware-player

Using ubuntu 10.04 the freeze happens during the spin-up of the dvd, after the dvd sends data the freeze goes away.
During the freeze no mouse-actions, no keyboard strokes are accepted. What could that be?

Comment: Try running `eject` in Terminal.

Comment: Why should i eject the disk if i want to access it? The question is: why the system freezes for about 10 seconds until the disk has spinned up?